# Change minor tick color in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

when I want to change the color of the ticks in matplotlib I can use

```
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')
```

but what if I also want to change the color of the minor ticks.
Can this be done easily?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at matplotlib's [major_minor_demo2 example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo2.html), it shows exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using [`ax.tick_params`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) you can pass a `which` keyword argument which will choose which ticks to modify.

The options are `major`, `minor`, or `both` with a default value `major`, which is why, by default, you aren't modifying your minor ticks.

For example:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', colors='red')
```

will set both major and minor ticks on the y axis to the colour red.